# How to join image and description in vertical timeline in css?

Tags: html, css

I have been created vertical timeline from this link http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Vertical-Timeline-With-jQuery-CSS3/

From above link, i had move to my web page.

Now my page look like this http://s7.postimg.org/i2ioc7rbv/Untitled_1.png

Now i need to join both sides of image and description.,

For that i created `<hr>`, but i just confused, how to join exactly.

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need something like this http://s7.postimg.org/yroplvdaz/Untitled_2.png

Comment: create relative div for each "row", inside it create 3 divs, one with a year number, one with some description and one with an image. Position description and image differently for odd and even rows (so you can switch sides of the image and the description)

Comment: can you please provide sample? @JanLegner . thanks

Comment: Now i see I got your question wrong: What you are trying to accomplish is that the description "arrives" to the mid-line and the picture appears?